# What is the coefficient of $x^{25}$ in $(x^3 + x + 1)^{10}$?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Here's what I have so far on the off chance that my thinking is correct...
So using Vieta's the coefficient of the $x^{25}$ should be $-(r_1r_2r_3r_4r_5+r_1r_3r_4r_5r_6+...+r_6r_7r_8r_9r_{10})$
Since each root is equal it is $-(r^5+r^5...+r^5)$
And there are 10 roots and you want to group them in 5's, so there are $10 \choose 5$ = 252 number of $r^5$s.

Have I gotten it right so far or are there errors in my work and/or line of reasoning?
I have $-252*(r^5)$ as the coefficient, with r being the solution to the cubic $x^3+x+1=0$.
How do I solve for r?

Would appreciate any help with this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not all three (repeated) roots are equal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way to get $x^{25}$ multiplying $10$ terms among 
$$
x^3,\,\,\,x\,\,\text{and}\,\,1, 
$$
is
$$
25=8\times 3+1\times 1+1\times 0,
$$
i.e.,
$$
x^{25}= (x^3)^8\cdot (x)^1\cdot (1)^1.
$$
[If we we $x^3$ seven times or less, then we get at most $x^{24}$, while if we use $x^3$ nine times or more, then we get at least $x^{27}$. Hence, we need to use $x^3$ eight times, and consequently, $x$ once, and $1$ once.]

Therefore, the coefficient we are looking for (i.e., the # of ways to choose 8 times $x^3$, once $x$ and once $1$) is
$$
N=\binom{10}{8}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}=90.
$$

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{a,b,c\in{\mathbb Z}}$:

\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\pars{x^{3} + x + 1}^{10}}
=\sum_{%
\vphantom{\huge A}a,b,c\ \geq\ 0\atop{\vphantom{\LARGE A}a\ +\ b\ +\ c\ =\ 10}}
{10! \over a!\ b!\ c!}\,\pars{x^{3}}^{a}x^{b}1^{c}
=\sum_{%
\vphantom{\huge A}a,b,c\ \geq\ 0\atop{\vphantom{\LARGE A}a\ +\ b\ +\ c\ =\ 10}}
{10! \over a!\ b!\ c!}\,x^{3a + b}
\end{align}

> With $\ds{3a + b = 25}$ and $\ds{a + b + c = 10}$ we'll have
>   $\ds{a = {15 + c \over 2}}$ and $\ds{b = {5 - 3c \over 2}}$. Also,
>   $\ds{0 \leq b\ \imp\ c \leq {5 \over 3}\ \imp\ c = 1}$ because $\ds{a}$ is an integer ( $\ds{c}$ must be odd ).

We get the $\ds{x^{25}}$-coefficient with
$\ds{\quad a = {15 + \color{#c00000}{1} \over 2} = 8\,,\quad
b = {5 - 3\times\color{#c00000}{1} \over 2} =1\,,\quad c = \color{#c00000}{1}}$:
$$
{10! \over 8!\ 1!\ 1!}=10\times 9=\color{#66f}{\Large 90}
$$